C++ Modules with complex (but valid) cyclical dependencies
Just to forestall and confusion, what I'm talking about is valid and trivially done with header files. However when I tried using modules, I can't wrap my head around a fix, and the SO examples didn't quite answer my specific use case.
If all I need is a pointer to the class in module B that imports module A, and module A imports module B and uses it fully, that would be trivially handled with a forward class declaration in B:
export class A;
export class B
{
    shared_ptr<A> a; // or pointer or whatever is needed
};

However, my specific need is more complex: I need a static portion of A in my B class, specifically (but not relevantly) a using type definition:
// A.ixx
import B;

export class A
{
    using T = function<const X&>; // depends on B, simplified

    void fn(const B&); // depends on B, simplified 
};

// B.ixx
export class B
{
    vector<A::T> v; // depends on A::T, a static type defined in A
};

As seen above, forward declaring A won't fix my issue. I could re-define A::T, but that's silly -- I might as well go back to header files at that point.
So how does this kind of pattern get solved idiomatically?

Is these classes are tightly coupled, why not put them both into the same module?

They're not that tightly coupled, they just reuse one common type. They're also rather large.

Can't you then put that one common type into it's own module C? That's similar to the solution you'd use if you had circular headers, and would actually make sense design-wise (if, as you said, both A and B reuse one common type).

Modules or not "cyclic" dependencies are IMO never OK.  They can always be resolved with dependency inversion. E.g. create a 3rd interface only module (with some abstract types). Doing that will give you better decomposition and (unit testability too, it allows for dependency injections of mocks/fakes/stubs)

Sometines code talks more than docs. Classes A and B in this senario are tightly coupled. Otherwise, it would be possible to define A::T as an alias to decltype(B::v)::value_type instead. Cyclic dependency prevention is a first step to kill static initialization order fiasco; It's not going anywhere.

I'll be real with you. I don't care about students' opinions on code, or alternative solutions. If you have an answer post it, otherwise you're just wasting your time.
